# Can Leshys have the Dhampir heritage?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, races

[Leshys](https://2e.aonprd.com/Ancestries.aspx?ID=14) have the Plant trait instead of Humanoid. [Dhampirs](https://2e.aonprd.com/Ancestries.aspx?ID=23) do not explicitly require Humanoid, but the text talks about things plants usually do not have:

> Some dhampirs are the **child** of one mortal and one vampiric **parent**, while others are **born** to those who were turned into vampires while **pregnant**. Still others rise from dark rituals or other supernatural influences that impose a vampiric curse onto a mortal **infant**.

Logically and lore-wise I would expect a Leshy Dhampir to be impossible, but the rules seem to disagree. Is this allowed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### It's allowed

There is no Prerequisite for a [Dhampir](https://2e.aonprd.com/Ancestries.aspx?ID=23) to be humanoid or make sense. It is allowed RAW, up to and including in PFS (if you have a Boon allowing Access to Dhampir) organized play.

That being said, it doesn't make *a lot* of sense, but there *are* a number of ways to justify it. The most obvious to me is if the spirit used to create the Leshy...

> Leshies are “born” when a skilled druid or other master of primal magic conducts a ritual to create a suitable vessel, and then a spirit chooses that vessel to be their temporary home.

... was a vampire in their previous life and had been destroyed. Alternatively, there are a number of [plants](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=408) on Golarion with vampiric traits. Dhampir could be a relatively easy way to represent Leshy bourne from those and similar plants. Finally, a Neutral Evil (going by the alignments used pre-Remaster) Druid may have reason to attempt to twist the spirit used in Leshy creation such that they feed on humanoids, in an effort to dissuade a growing settlement from encroaching on the nearby wild lands.

Comment: Feed me, Seymour!